# Pandas Aggregate Data By Column Names and sum the data inside with step of 5

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have data like this:

```
timestamp                101     100     105    109    110      112
2020-11-01 12:00:00       4       3       5      0      0        1        
2020-11-01 12:01:00       4       9       5      3      1        1
2020-11-01 12:02:00       4       15      0      3      2        2 
2020-11-01 12:03:00       4       15      0      3      2        2
2020-11-01 12:05:00       4       15      0      3      2        3
2020-11-01 12:06:00       4       15      0      3      2        0
```

I want it to group by columns with a step of 5 and sum the inner data
The resulting dataframe would be it should sort the columns first before doing the aggregate:

```
timestamp                100     105     110       
2020-11-01 12:00:00       12       0       1               
2020-11-01 12:01:00       18       4       2          
2020-11-01 12:02:00       19       5       4           
2020-11-01 12:03:00       19       5       4  
... 
...
```

Additionally, want to add the missing row with the previous rows data (12:04:00)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
out = df.set_index('timestamp').groupby(lambda x : int(x)//5*5,axis=1).sum()
Out[295]: 
                    100  105  110
timestamp                        
2020-11-0112:00:00    7    5    1
2020-11-0112:01:00   13    8    2
2020-11-0112:02:00   19    3    4
2020-11-0112:02:00   19    3    4
2020-11-0112:02:00   19    3    5
2020-11-0112:02:00   19    3    2
```

Comment: The above works perfectly. I updated the question for an additional feature if you could help. I want to fill the missing timestamp 12:04:00 in above with data from 12:02:00, my timestamp field is the index but it's in Timestamp() format. Could you help with this?

Comment: @PavneetSingh I think it would be better if we open a new topic for your follow up new question